# How to link text to mouse pointer?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make text that follows my mouse pointer, but getting some troubles.
I'm using fullscreen `div` to take available space on page to make mouse event working for entire page.
Also using `position: absolute` to place one `div` on another. date-and-time is used to create text that follows the mouse.
I've tried almost anything I can but it didn't work and now I'm here.

*html*

```html
<body> 
  <div id="fullscreen"></div>
  <div id="date-and-time"></div>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
```

*javascript*

```js
const dateAndTime = document.getElementById('date-and-time');
dateAndTime.innerText = new Date();

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  dateAndTime.style.left = e.clientX;
  dateAndTime.style.top = e.clientY;
});
```

*css*

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
}

#fullscreen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Problem is that text just ignores my mouse, but if I move pointer to left corner text gets moved to `X=0` (maybe it's not actually but it worked that way before)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078576/mouse-pointer-with-text-tooltip) solve your issue?

Comment: Tested it in Chrome, everything works, but text change it's position only after mouse was moved. Initially text is in top left corner.

Comment: Btw, it's better to set `margin: 0` for `body` rather than use fullscreen-div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `px` for the postion values.

You are assigning the left and right position values to the node without `px`.

What happens when you move to left most position? Simple at that time the value will be `0`. That will work without any unit.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
}

#fullscreen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="fullscreen"></div>
  <div id="date-and-time"></div>
</body>
<script>
  const dateAndTime = document.getElementById("date-and-time");
  dateAndTime.innerText = new Date();

  document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    dateAndTime.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
    dateAndTime.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
  });
</script>
```